# Echo cancellation in pjsua2 in android not working.(Not with webrtc.)

Tags: android, echo-cancellation, pjsua2

I am trying to eliminate echo in my voip call app. I'm using pjsua2 library. I tried the following code in the "MyApp" class provided in pjsua2 sample app.

```
    /* Echo cancellation */
    try {
        ep.audDevManager().setEcOptions(128, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    epConfig.getMedConfig().setEcOptions(0);
    epConfig.getMedConfig().setEcTailLen(128);
```

I still hear echo. What changes should I make in the code? Is there anything to be done at the time of building pjsua library? I don't want to use webrtc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data sheet for AEC alternative with PJSIP. I suggest to test them and find the best solution for your environment.  https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSIP-Datasheet